# Writing to SQLite Database objective C Iphone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, sqlite

I need help writing new entries into an SQLite database using Objective C and the iPhone SDK.

The open/close/read database operations go okay, but I can't work out why this bit of code is not working.

```
-(void) testWriteToDatabase{

NSLog(@"instructions sent 3");
    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
const char *insertSql="INSERT INTO data (name,pass,email) VALUES(?,?,?)";

NSString *userRegistered=userRegister.text;
NSLog(@"user %@",userRegistered);
NSString *passRegistered=passRegister.text;
NSLog(@"pass %@",passRegistered);
NSString *emailRegistered=emailRegister.text;
NSLog(@"email %@",emailRegistered);
sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt = nil;



if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertSql, -1, &insertStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

NSLog(@"instructions sent 4");
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 1, [userRegistered UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 2, [passRegistered UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 3, [emailRegistered UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            NSLog(@"instructions sent 5");
        while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


        }

     }
sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);    
    }
sqlite3_close(database);    
}
```

To honest, I've never really used SQLite before, but the main problem is it's not adding entries to the database 'data' like i want it to. Help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Any reason you're talking directly to sqlite and not bothering with Core Data?

Comment: I would highly recommend using Gus Mueller's FMDatabase wrapper classes around SQLite.  https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: I want to be able to download/upload the database to a server, so it's not restrictive. And to be honest, I never really considered it :/

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: real non-masochists use `NSCoding`, `NSKeyedArchiver`, `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, `NSArray` and `NSSet`.

Comment: @WTP don't forget `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
}
```

be

```
while (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
}
```

as you've used `insertStmt` everywhere else. `compiledStatement` is undefined as I understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Does the database have a table called "data"? Trivial thing, but still. Also, do check what does the `sqlite3_step` return on every step.

Comment: Yeah it does have a table called data, and okay i'll check for that.

Comment: I'm struggling to find the code that calls what the Sqlite3_step function returns... - as i say i'm a complete novice with SQLite :/

Comment: I ran this command: `NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %d", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));` The answer that it returned was 0.